# How to fix Type '(event: any, el: any) => void' is not assignable to type '(arg: { isMirror: boolean; isStart: boolean;

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, events, fullcalendar

I've been receiving this error in Angular's FullCalendar v4 when I tried altering the event content DOM.

```
ERROR in src/app/shared/components/calendar/calendar.component.ts:67:13 - error TS2322: Type '(event: any, el: any) => void' is not assignable to type '(arg: { isMirror: boolean; isStart: boolean; isEnd: boolean; event: EventApi; el: HTMLElement; view: View; }) => void'.
    
    67             eventRender: function(event, el) {
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~
    
      node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.d.ts:322:9
        322         eventRender?(arg: {
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        323             isMirror: boolean;
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        ... 
        328             view: View;
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        329         }): void;
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        The expected type comes from property 'eventRender' which is declared here on type 'OptionsInput'
```

Not sure if I've used the eventRender property correctly, as I think this just happens in Angular. You can see how I've used it in initializeCalendar() function.

Here's my typescript file:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, Input, Output, EventEmitter, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Calendar } from '@fullcalendar/core';
import { CalendarService } from '@services/calendar.service';
import { CALENDAR_FILTERS } from '@shared/constants';
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction';
import moment from 'moment';

const MINI = 'mini-calendar';
const FULL = 'full-calendar';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-calendar',
  templateUrl: './calendar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./calendar.component.scss']
})
export class CalendarComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

    calendarFilters: any;
    calendar: Calendar;
    isLoading: boolean;

    @Input() eventSource: (startDate: any, endDate: any, callback: any, filters: any) => any;
    @Input() withFilters: boolean;
    @Input() appearance: string;
    @Output() onDateClick = new EventEmitter();
    @Output() onEventClick = new EventEmitter();

    constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef, private calendarService: CalendarService) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {}

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        if (this.withFilters) {
            this.calendarService.fetchCalendarFilters().subscribe((res) => {
                this.calendarFilters = res.calendar_filter
                    ? JSON.parse(res.calendar_filter.config)
                    : CALENDAR_FILTERS.slice(0);
                this.initializeCalendar();
                this.addCalendarFiltersSection();
            });

            return;
        }

        this.initializeCalendar();
    }

    initializeCalendar() {
        let calendarEl = document.getElementById('common-calendar');
        this.calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
            plugins: [dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin],
            header: {
                left: this.appearance == MINI ? 'title' : '',
                center: this.appearance == MINI ? '' : 'title',
                right: 'prev, today, next'
            },
            eventSources: [this.fetchEvents.bind(this)],
            dateClick: this.dateClick.bind(this),
            eventClick: this.eventClick.bind(this),
            displayEventEnd: true,
            eventTimeFormat: { 
                hour: 'numeric',
                minute: '2-digit',
                meridiem: 'short'
            },
            eventRender: function(event, el) {
                el.find(".fc-event-title").remove();
                el.find(".fc-event-time").remove();
                var new_description =   
                    moment(event.start).format("HH:mm") + '-'
                    + moment(event.end).format("HH:mm") + '<br/>'
                    + event.customer + '<br/>'
                    + '<strong>Address: </strong><br/>' + event.address + '<br/>'
                    + '<strong>Task: </strong><br/>' + event.task + '<br/>'
                    + '<strong>Place: </strong>' + event.place + '<br/>'
                ;
                el.append(new_description);
            }
        });
        this.calendar.render();
    }


    refetchEvents() {
        this.calendar.refetchEvents();
    }

    fetchEvents(info, successCallback, failureCallback) {
        this.eventSource(info.startStr, info.endStr, successCallback, this.calendarFilters);
    }

    dateClick(info) {
        this.onDateClick.emit(info)
    }

    eventClick(info) {
        this.onEventClick.emit(info);
    }

    onCalendarFilterClick(event) {
        this.isLoading = true;
        const calendar_event = event.target.id;

        this.calendarFilters.includes(calendar_event)
            ? this.calendarFilters.splice(this.calendarFilters.indexOf(calendar_event), 1)
            : this.calendarFilters.push(calendar_event);

        this.calendarService.setCalendarFilters({ config: this.calendarFilters }).subscribe(calendar => {
            this.isLoading = false;
        });
        this.generateButtonEventFilters(this.calendarFilters);
        this.calendar.refetchEvents();
    }

    setLoader(value) {
        this.isLoading = value;
    }

    private addCalendarFiltersSection() {
        var el = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.fc-view-container');
        let html = '<div class="btn-group-events" id="custom-buttons"></div>';

        el.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', html);
        this.generateButtonEventFilters(this.calendarFilters);
    }

    private generateButtonEventFilters(calendarFilters) {
        let buttons = '';

        CALENDAR_FILTERS.forEach(function (event, index) {
            buttons += `<button type="button" id="${event}" class="${
                calendarFilters.includes(event) ? 'btn-event' : 'btn-event btn-event-active'
            }">
        ${event.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + event.substring(1)}</button>`;
        });

        document.getElementById('custom-buttons').innerHTML = buttons;
        this.addHandlers();
    }

    private addHandlers() {
        CALENDAR_FILTERS.forEach((calendar_event) => {
            this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector(`#${calendar_event}`).addEventListener('click', (event) => {
                this.onCalendarFilterClick(event);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Any advise is much appreciated.

Comment: `Not sure if I've used the eventRender property correctly`...so did you check the documentation? See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/eventRender . As you'll see, the answer to your question is "no". You appear to have used syntax from version 3 or earlier.

Comment: Oh, yeah sorry about that. Thank you for the direction.